# Java: use other program's static method's output in my program

Tags: java, processbuilder

I need to read a byte[] produced by another java program I wrote.
As known, main in java can only return a void. Does this mean I need to write a program with a static method with the return type byte[] ?
If yes, how can I then run this method in my program and save it's return value in my programm? this is what I have in my program:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java.exe","viewer.java","pathToViewer.java");
Process process = pb.start();
InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
```

What is the right way?

Comment: What higher-level problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: why can't you just call another program from within your program? Why do you need to use ProcessBuilder?

Comment: @Simon open a .dcm file and convert it to byte[] in the Android SDK. the only way to open it is the plugin for ImageIO, and Android SDK does not support it in any way, even if I add all .jars correctly it won't compile. so I've managed to convert it to byte[] in another external program and now I want to get this byte[]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't communicate return values across JVM instances. You must devise and implement a specific protocol that will pass the data. One simple option you have is writing to `System.out` in the subprocess, which will push the data into your `is`, so your `bytes` will end up containing what the subprocess wrote.

Comment: do you think it would work to just pipe the console output from one program to the console input of the other program?

Comment: @MarcoForberg You mean, don't use `Runtime#exec` at all? That may depend on the platform OP is on, but if on Linux, I think it would work. Only, it is a highly unusual approach for Java, probably due to the multiplatform issues with that.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thank you. so in my external programm I can output the bytes in form of a string with System.out.println() and then capture it by the is in the "main" program and convert it to byte[]?

Comment: If you need bytes, then use `out.write(byte[])` to avoid any encoding issues.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik the thing with porcess builder I wrote seems to write just null to the input stream. what is the correct way to execute an external program ?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik was just wondering if this would work at all from one jvm to another. We had to use this aproach some years ago at university in c++ and i wondered if it would work in java as well

Comment: @MarcoForberg On a \*nix I have no reason to doubt it would work. Java uses the regular `stdin` and `stdout`, and a pipe will connect two Java processes just like any others.